# How do you decide on a typeface?

Tags: typography, page-layout, typefaces

Do you go through all your fonts and choose the best one?

Do you find a typeface you like and get variations of it?

Do you copy your favorite typeface combination from a cool looking website?

Do you visit typewolf, googlefonts, fontsinuse, to get 'inspired'?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this chart, it can also be found here 
https://inspirationlab.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/infographiclarge_v2.png 
 [image: Typeface chart]

Other than that, take a look at these two articles.

**How to choose a font**

1. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/12/what-font-should-i-use-five-principles-for-choosing-and-using-typefaces/

**How to combine fonts**

2. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/best-practices-of-combining-typefaces/

Comment: Love the route that takes you to Comic Sans on that chart haha

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: Realize that image was created more for *humor* than actual workflow. While some routes end in an okay, although pedestrian typeface, most routes kind of lead you to a novice decision.

Comment: Novice is a good place to start. If you have no clue, then you can find a style of font to start you of.
But also it's fun, there should always be room for a little fun, right?